# ASP MVC Razor View with a large embedded Image throw CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a view that has a large embedded image, like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU.......YII=" />
```

When the image is too large the scr attribute is very large (it can have 2 mega characteres) I get the error:
CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile

But, if the src attribute has less characteres (ex: 300,000 characteres) the view works perfectly.

How can I use large embedded images in a razor view?

Answer (score 0):

[You only shold use base64 images when the image is small.](http://davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/)

You can try converting the base64 string to an image using this:

```
public Image Base64ToImage(string base64String)
{
  // Convert Base64 String to byte[]
  byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, 
    imageBytes.Length);

  // Convert byte[] to Image
  ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
  Image image = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
  return image;
}
```

if your image is a static resource you can try put it in a [`<text>` or `:@`](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax)

```
<text>
    <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSU.......YII=" />
</text>
```